# Ionic4: How to open external link from Side Menu

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

On my ionic project, I have created side menu at `app.html` to be available through the whole app, this menu contains items with links that should be opened externally. I have tried to open them with InAppBrowser but I have this error pups up:

```
uncaught (in promise) invalid views to insert
```

app.html:

```
<ion-list no-margin>
            <ion-item menuClose ion-item no-lines *ngFor="let l of SocialLinks" (click)="openPage(l.Url)">
                <ion-icon name="{{l.icon}}"></ion-icon>

           </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

...


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
  providers: [InAppBrowser]
})

...

constructor(
...
 private iab: InAppBrowser
)    

...  

this.SocialLinks = [

     { title: 'twitter', Url: 'https://twitter.com', icon: 'logo-twitter' },
     { title: 'facebook', Url: 'https://facebook.com', icon: 'logo-facebook' },
     { title: 'instagram', Url: 'https://instagram.com', icon: 'logo-instagram' },
     { title: 'linkedin', Url: 'https://linkedin.com', icon: 'linkedin' },

];


...


OpenUrl(Url: string, myEvent) {
    const browser = this.iab.create(Url);
    browser.show();
  }
```

is there any way to open those links from the side menu?

Comment: You want to open the inappbrowser in the app or you want them to jump to the browser outside of the app?

Comment: @AbdullahRasheed I would prefer to open it inappbrowser, I tried to open it with the device browser using this code: `window.open(Url,'_system', 'location=yes');` but still gave the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you noticed that the method you call in the `click` is not the same one you call when you show an Ionic Page

Comment: please don't answer questions with a question.

Comment: It was a question for being polite and not taking for granted that this was the mistake, since they have not put the complete code.

Comment: Then you should have posted this as a comment not an answer.