# ionic link side menu item to external website

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

I am trying to link the side menu item to an external website, but it doesn't seem to work

Below is my code

```
{
  title: 'Word of the Week',
  url: '/word',
  icon: './assets/sample-icons/side-menu/word.svg'
},
{
  title: 'Facebook',
  url: 'https://www.fb.com',
  icon: './assets/sample-icons/side-menu/fb.svg'
},
```

I tried removing https, starting with  www and other modifications but they don't seem to make it work

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I checked this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52427032/ but that doesn't seem to provide solution to my problem

Comment: you can acheve this by using [InAppBrowser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Angular escapes the URL for security reasons (see https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer ).

Here is a good solution, that uses a redirect guard: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51059505/3530591